# ¿Cómo mostrar productos separados por categorías?

Tags: php, mysql

En el index tengo un navegador vertical con todas las categorías de mis productos, lo que necesito es que al hacer clic en cada botón se muestre sólo esa categoría, por ahora logro mostrar los productos pero estoy llamando a todos los productos en el primer botón, y necesito que se muestren por separado.

Esto es lo que tengo...

Al inicio:

```
<?php require_once('conection.php'); ?>
<?php
    $max=6;
    $pag=0;

    if(isset($_GET[pag]) && $_GET[pag] <>""){
        $pag=$_GET[pag];
    }
    $inicio=$pag * $max;

    if(isset($_GET[s])&&$_GET[s]<>""){
        $whe="AND product LIKE '%$_GET[s]%' ";
    }

    if(isset($_GET[cat])&&$_GET[cat]<>""){
        $whe.="AND product LIKE '%$_GET[cat]%' ";
    }

    $query="SELECT id, product, productcode, state, category, description, price FROM products  ORDER BY date DESC";
    $query_limit= $query . " LIMIT $inicio,$max";
    $resource = $conn->query($query_limit);

    if (isset($_GET[total])) {
        $total = $_GET[total];
    } else {    
        $resource = $conn->query($query);
        $total = $resource->num_rows;   
    }
    $total_pag = ceil($total/$max)-1;
?>
```

Botón para mostrar la categoría:

```
<a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-americanshotguns-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-americanshotguns" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-americanshotguns" aria-selected="true">AMERICAN SHOTGUNS</a>
```

Finalmente donde se debe mostrar la categoría:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-americanshotguns" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-americanshotguns-tab">
    <?php if($total){?>
        <?php while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){?>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <figure class="product-index">
                    <img src="images/american-shotguns/<?php echo $row[productcode]?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row[product]?>" class="img-fluid rounded">
                <figcaption class="fig-product-index"> <h6><strong><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row[id]?>"><?php echo $row[product]?></a></strong></h6> <br> <p><strong>~ <?php echo $row[state]?> ~</strong></p> </figcaption>
                </figure>                                       
            </div>
        <?php }?>
    <?php  }else{?>
        <p> Results not found.</p>
    <?php }?>   
</div>
```

Agradezco su ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo hacerlo desde el Query SQL, utiliza un group by y de ahi crear un arreglo para cada categoría. Ejemplo $Categories['Categorie1'] = $row['item']. Te dejo documentación sobre cómo elaborar el query  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo intentare y te cuento que tal!